# Using dates in Coldfusion 1 and Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to select from a table with two dates datatype, start and end dates in Oracle 11g.
I wrote:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM mytable
        WHERE date_received BETWEEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" 
        value="#CreateODBCDate(Form.startDate)#">
        AND <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"
        value="#CreateODBCDate(Form.EndDate)#">
```

I got an error:
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver]Conversion error - Year in date/timestamp parameter is out of range.
When I enter startdate: 09122014 & end date: 09122015 I got:
start date: {d '26875-03-22'}
end date : {d '27176-05-24'}

Then I tried to_date function of Oracle 11g:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM mytable
        WHERE date_received BETWEEN <cfqueryparam 
        cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#to_date(Form.startDate, 
        'DD-MM-YY')#">
        AND <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" 
        value="#to_date(Form.EndDate, 'DD-MM-YY')#">
```

I got this error:
to_date variable is not defined

How can I do a select in ColdFusion with Oracle 11g back end? I did not have this problem when they're still using Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

> When I enter startdate: 09122014

[CreateODBCDate()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6def.html) expects a valid date *object*. Technically it accepts date *strings* as well, but as with most of CF's "auto-magic-string-to-date-object" conversions, you are stuck with however CF chooses to interpret the input strings. In this case, CF interprets `09122014` a numeric representation of a date object, or 9122014 days from the CF epoch ie {d '26875-03-22'}.

If you choose to rely on CF's automatic conversion, then the date strings must be formatted according to standard U.S. date conventions, such as "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy-mm-dd". Both formats will produce the correct result. Using a hard coded value for illustration:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#CreateODBCDate('09/12/2014')#">
```

Having said that, CF date functions are notoriously generous with they considered a "date".  IMO, you are better off validating the strings and constructing your own date objects with [CreateDate()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/CreateDate).

> `to_date` variable is not defined

`TO_DATE` is an Oracle function. CF knows nothing about your dbms functions. Those should be placed outside the cfqueryparam tag. Also, the function is expecting a string in the specified mask format. Something like this:

```
TO_DATE(  <cfqueryparam value="09122014" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
         , 'MMDDYYYYY'
        )
```

Comment: I want to thank you for the tip. I never know I can do:TO_DATE(  <cfqueryparam value="09122014" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
         , 'MMDDYYYYY'
        )

Comment: Welcome. Even if you choose to go with TO_DATE, you should still validate the input string in CF, before the query.  No need to waste a db call if the string will ultimate fail the TO_DATE conversion.